# Exporting Code to a word Doc with formatting

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to export code to a word doc from a Google Script, and I want to preserve the formatting so a reader can more easily follow the logic. However, when I do, it reformats to the target formatting (plain black text, same font, same size, etc.). I would like to keep the font, color, and other formatting.

For example, when I copy and paste code ([source](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-recurrence#addMonthlyExclusion())), my ACTUAL RESULT:

> // Creates a rule that recurs every month for three months.
>    var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addMonthlyRule().times(4);

whereas my INTENDED RESULT is (see first link).

From the website, I can use the "click to copy" button in the upper corner to export the code chunk with formatting, but I have no idea how to replicate this.

Thanks for your help!

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

The color and other formatting you're seeing in that web page link you've provided is made in the [HTML and CSS code of that page](http://www.webnots.com/view-webpage-source-css-in-google-chrome/) which you can observe when you right-click the page and choose "Inspect" in the context menu. So it was styled that way using programming. You can't just copy paste the text and expect it to work.

This won't work on your Google Doc format as it's an entirely different thing. Don't mix them up.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your response!